# Google Sheets Script Code to send emails (once) based on row having any value

Tags: javascript

Please help.

I have a Google Sheets (with only one sheet called "Sheet1) with two columns, the first one with "Names" as a header (A1) and the other as "Last Names" as header (B1).  Therefore data starts on A2.

The following code (see below) will send emails to all recipients listed in the code and it will automatically insert an "EMAIL SENT" on column C which allows the code to determine which records already have an email sent.

The code below works, except for four things I need modified:

1. I cannot make it work to automatically send emails for any unlimited
   number of unprocessed rows.  As the code is right now, it only sends
   emails for the first two records.  Yes, you can manually change the
   "2" to "2000" but instead **I need it to find automatically all the row as when using the getLastRow()** but I can't figure out how to do so (I'm new to this so even when I manually change it to 6 or 10 rows I cannot make it work).
2. I need the "EMAIL SENT" status inserted in column L (column 12) instead - or any other column of my choosing.  Again, when I tried the code stops working.
3. I need to insert parts of the row content (of my choosing) in the automatic email "message" area; maybe by setting variables that can easily be inserted or excluded depending on what is needed at the time. Perhaps even making this code work in conjunction of an html template?
4. Finally, I would like the code to start sending email with row 3.

Here is the code which works except for the four modification deeded:

Code (which I slightly modified) found at:  [Google App Script site](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails)

NOTE: the emails used in the code are fake. You have to replace them with real ones to test the solution offered.

```js
// This constant is written in column C for rows for which an email
// has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';

/**
 * Sends non-duplicate emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
 */
function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 6);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = "jdoe1@email.net" + "," + "jdoe2@email.com";
    var message = "See below the student(s) who has/have completed the orientation.";
    var emailSent = row[2]; // Third column
    if (emailSent !== EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = 'Student(s) COMPLETED the Orientation.';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

In advance, thank you so very much for any help provided.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the modified and working code, which could have not been done without the help of Mike Steelson.  Thank you Mike.

This code now will send automatic emails up to the last row of data (not only two rows as the original example) and it will not send duplicates.

Don't forget to set the trigger so that it is done automatically.

NOTE:  in this example, my sheet has 12 columns total.  This includes the column (L) where the EMAIL_SENT status is written (that's where I want it placed, on the last column of my table, column 12). Also, row 2 is where I have the column headers. Therefore, the data starts on row 3.

```js
// This constant is written in column L for rows for which an email
    // has been sent successfully.
    var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT'; // This is written on column 12, change to the column you want

    /**
     * Sends non-duplicate emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
     */
    function sendEmails2() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var startRow = 3; // First row of data to process (row 2 would contains the column headers, and row 1 the spreadsheet title)
      var numRows = sheet.getLastRow(); // Number of rows to process, this picks up to the last row that has data
      // Fetch the range of cells A3:L3, columns 1 through 12
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows-startRow+1,12); // column 12, where the EMAIL_SENT status is written, change to the column you want
      // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
      var data = dataRange.getValues();
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        var row = data[i];
        var emailAddress = "neo@gmail.com, neo@hotmail.com"; //FAKE email - write here a real email to test it
        var message = "See the worksheet to find the student(s) who has/have completed the orientation." + row[-1] + row[-1] ;
        var emailSent = row[11];; // In this area, the 11 is actually column 12. On this line, columns are identified with array values which start with 0 and not 1
        if (emailSent !== EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates
          var subject = 'Student(s) COMPLETED the orientation.';
          MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
          //Logger.log(emailAddress + ' ' + subject + ' ' + message)
          sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 12).setValue(EMAIL_SENT); // column 12, where the EMAIL_SENT status is written
          // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
          SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        }
      }
    }
    // Remember:  to change the column where the EMAIL_SENT status is written
    // you must change the corresponding lines where you see the 12, for column 12
    // and the one row where it says 11, which is actually column 12
    //
    // Also, don't forget to set a trigger from the Script window, under "View, Current Project's Triggers"
    // then the trigger to:
    // -function to run:  sendEmail2
    // -deployment:  Head
    // -event source:  From Spreadsheet
    // -event type:  On edit   < ------ this is crucial
    // -Failure notification settings:  Notify me immediately
```

Answer (score 0):

1. change numRows as following

   ```
   var numRows=sheet.getLastRow()
   // and
   var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows-startRow+1, 6);
   ```
2. change 2 lignes

   ```
   var col = 12 (column L)
   var emailSent = row[col-1];
   // and
   sheet.getRange(startRow + i, col).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
   ```
3. complete `message` with y and z the column (minus 1)

   ```
   var message = "bla bla" + row[y] + " - " + row[z] ;
   ```
4. ```
    var startRow = 3;
   ```

Comment: 1.  If I add var numRows=sheets.getLastRow(), I keep getting emails for  blank rows past the last row that has data.  It does not detect the last row that actually has data.  This is the glitch I was having on my own.  I am thinking that this is linked to the next line of code:  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 6).

Comment: 2. The suggestion given did not work, but it pointed out what I needed to do.  So I got that.

Comment: 3.  The suggestion on how to add:  var message = "bla bla" + row[y] + " - " + row[z] ;  it gives the error message of "ReferenceError y is not define" and then no emails are sent.  Nothing gets added to the "Message".

Comment: 4. The suggestion for this did work.

Comment: 3. Obviously y and z must be a number as I said in my answer

Comment: 1. give us a complete view of yous sheet, plus share a copy of it.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YWsm2_WZu-cVmIgQh1ZN9AJIau0yykM7p_WDi56JmKs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YWsm2_WZu-cVmIgQh1ZN9AJIau0yykM7p_WDi56JmKs/edit#gid=0

Comment: 2. Sorry, I change a little and replace x by col, see my updated answer

Comment: 1. Change dataRange as indicated in my updated answer

Comment: Thanks.  That did it.  I will post the whole code for the benefit of other.